# How to put an extra dot on a plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

A matrix has 3000X7000 cells. NANs and values. The non-NAN values are concentrated in a particular region which I plot using this:

```
select = ~isnan(Dgrid);
[r1,c1] = find(select);
df = Dgrid(min(r1)-2 : max(r1)+2, min(c1)-2 : max(c1)+2); 
imagesc(df)
```

In the main image,

```
min(r1) = 1208
max(r1) = 1235
min(c1) = 5809
max(c1) = 5843
```

I want to put a marker on exactly this cell: row: 1218, col = 5842.

Not sure how I can convert the row/col of the larger image to the smaller image.

[image]

Comment: `hold on; plot(x,y,'.','markersize',20)` ??

Comment: @xvan more like `hold on; plot(1218 - min(r1) - 1, 5842 - min(c1) - 1, '.')` ...

Comment: @zeeMonkeez It's putting the dot at the wrong place.....